# Define a map that looks like a solid

Tags: functions, vectors

Let $S$ be a solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we are viewing it from the x-axis, in the front, it looks like a circle, a rectangle from the side, and equilateral triangle from above, all centered at the origin.

I'm not even sure what a solid like this will look like, so how can we define the map $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y,z) = (y,z)$?

And how can we describe $f(S)$ using sets?

Comment: The map $f:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ clearly is defined (you actually defined it) so what is the question? Whether such a solid exists?

Comment: How can we describe $f(S)$ using sets.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly to your scale, but your figure looks like a toothpaste tube.

[image]

And $f$ is just the projection on the $yz$ plane

Comment: I'm not understanding how it will look like an equilateral triangle from above.

Comment: The picture I've found has the wrong axes orientation. Rotate the tube so that the opening points horizontally along the $x$ axis. What the image shows is the view from the side (rectangle). The above view in your problem is the view from left or right for this tube, which is a triangle. To get it equilateral, just make it shorter.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! Need to spend some time on $f(S)$, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In this picture $x$ is the vertical axis, so $f$ is the projection in the horizontal plane. It is the shadow on a horizontal plane if the light is above.